# Mod Rewrite - Regular Expression equal sign in the URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess i have a rewrite rules which reads values from a clean looking url.

I need to send all the ( vanity ) url to `request.php` except a URL with this path: `/change-email/[number ( and or ) character and the '=' sign]`

All work fine but when the string had a equal sign is intercepted from other rules.

Examples:

`mysite.com/change-email/` --> go to `request.php` [ok]

`mysite.com/change-email` --> go to `request.php` [ok]

mysite.com/change-email/dasu564345ytfghafsfda --> go to `change-email.php` [ok]

mysite.com/change-email/dasu564345ytfghafsfda= -->go to `request.php` [not ok] it should go to `/includes/change-email.php`

is the 3° rule in **main app section**

this is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#main app rules
RewriteRule ^change-email(\/|)?$ /request.php?key=change-email [QSA]
RewriteRule ^change-email/([\w+]{1,})(\/|)?$ /includes/change-email.php?email=$1 [QSA] <-- need to catch = sign!
RewriteRule ^([\w+]{1,})(\/|)?$ /request.php?&key=$1 [QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /request.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` doesn't consider `=`. Try following regex for `change-email.php` url:

`^change-email/([\w\=]{1,})(\/|)?$`